# How to display GPS with raspberry pi 3 from fona 808 using python programming language?

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, adafruit

How to display location data with raspberry pi 3 from fona 808 using python programming language?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question on Stack Overflow. Post on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
import Serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0',115200)
ser.write(b'AT+CGNSPWR=1\n')
#Wait for GPS data
time.sleep(5)
ser.write(b'AT+CGPSINF=0\n')
ser.write(b'AT+CGNSPW=0\n')
while ser.inWaiting > 0:
    print(ser.readline())
ser.close()
```

It works for me.